# How to deploy ASP.NET Core package with bower packages

Tags: deployment, asp.net-core, bower

I have a (no more) simple application which was written just for fun, but it turned out that someone wants to buy it. The application is written in ASP.NET Core 1.1, with a few controllers that just serve plain partial views. The web application itself sits in wwwroot folder, it utilizes angular, kendo UI and several javascript libraries like moment.js, linqjs and so on. The packages are managed by bower, apart from kendo ui which was installed manually. What is the recommended way to deploy it - the client expects to get a zip file or some installator which he will use on his iis server. When I published the application to my IIS server just to check if it works, it turned out that all the lib folder (filled with stuff installed by bower) was publish too, even with demo files that some plugins provide. What is the recommended way to deploy only the necessary files but also to provide minification&bundling.